# Issue with application files folder in android

Tags: android, file-permissions

I'm trying to create zip file inside my application files folder (/data/data/myapp/files) but getting "failed to create zip file | open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)" error message every time. As I can see using android debug bridge, my files folder have "rwx------" permissions and "root" owner and group. I think this is the problem but I can't understand why my folder have this owner and group?

Comment: is your device rooted?

Comment: by the way I'm change owner and group to my application uid and still got same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by manually setting right owner, group and permissions on my application files folder (using chmod, chown and chgrp commands). It does not seem like an answer, because it is still unclear why this folder got wrong permissions but unfortunately I don't have enough time to understand where problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you :

- have rooted your device
- have the rights to write on the internal storage
- are not trying to test it with the usb storage enabled on your phone
- added the permission `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />` in your manifest

Comment: - Yes, device is rooted. Usb storage is disabled. Even if not, I think this can't cause problems because only external storage remounted in usb storage mode. It seems there is no such permission, but I tried add it for sure. No results.

Comment: May if you could add more of the stack trace